# SKSpriteNode does not get updated

Tags: swift, skspritenode

I simply want a spritenode to move when it was clicked. But it seems the Scene does not update until a second click on the other spritenode click occurs.

Where is my mistake?

```
override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
    cardLayer = SKNode()
    addChild(cardLayer)
    sprite = SKSpriteNode()
    let cardSize = CGSize(width: 80,height: 100)
    sprite.size = cardSize
    sprite.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "1.png")
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
    sprite.name = "123"
    cardLayer.addChild(sprite)
    sprite1 = SKSpriteNode()
    sprite1.size = cardSize
    sprite1.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "1.png")
    sprite1.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 300)
    sprite1.name = "123"
    cardLayer.addChild(sprite1)
}




override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let array = Array(touches)
    let touch = array[0] 
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = atPoint(location)
    if let _ = touchedNode.name {
        print("moved")
        touchedNode.position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: Work on the line that says if let _ = touchedNode.name {

Comment: Could you please sepcify what you mean by "Work on". The node has a name, so the line is correct in my point of view. My problem is that the node does not get updated by just changing the postion. Why is that so? (If I add an action here it works, but this is just an example - in the end I have a function that updates the position and images of over 50 nodes)

Comment: Ask Google or whoever is good at the search engine search about the node name.

Comment: Sorry, but "ask google" is really not helping.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do what you are trying to do.

I think you should try the **nodes(at: )** instead.

here is an example of it in use

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


if let touch = touches.first {
//gets location
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
//gets of what nodes are at the location
            let object = nodes(at: location)
// if the there is a node on that location that is the sprite I want
            if object.contains(yourSprite){
//you can put what ever numbers you want to run in there. This simply
// determines the direction of the movement based on a t-Graph
                yourSprite.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -5, duration: 1))
            }
}
```

Comment: nodes(at:) is just the Swift 3 version of location(in:).

Comment: I just checked my code and it worked perfectly fine, and it does get what you want done.

Comment: the reason your code works is  yourSprite.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -5, duration: 1)) and not nodes(at:). nodes(at:) has been renamed in newer Swift versions. But I need to get the Sprite updated without executing an animation... If that is possible.

Comment: I am running the latest version of Xcode, so I have no clue what you are talking about updates. Also that isn't the "reason" why it works.